# nodejs callback code is synchronized

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I am learning nodejs prons and cons to make my new project. One doubts I still unclear  i.e. code inside callback function in synchronized or thread safe ?

I knew that nodejs is working with single thread and its handovering execution in some other process inside callback function. However in case if first callback request would take time and second request come with different data then its creates havoc?

If its thread safe means every time its creating new thread inside callback function?

Comment: no, there is only one thread at any time, but it can wait on other threads/processes without doing work. normal JS program flow determines the execution order of nested callbacks, to the extent you've set them up to be raced, serial, parallel, etc. just brushup on async programming, but trust that JS does something repeatable and reliable.

Comment: `creating new thread` No.  Node.js is **strictly single-threaded**.

Comment: if it helps, all JS code is always sync, js alone cannot provide async, though setTimeout can fake it. anything that provides async (file loading, http, cmd, etc) comes from the host environment, not the JS core. so while the JS itself runs on a single thread, different external activities will of course use more processes under the hood. then return the results back to the JS thread, where program flow resume as expected.

Comment: Thanks for instant comments. If main thread is leaving execution in callback means some another Thread should handover from main thread to complete callback execution right ?

Comment: @dandavis So data under the callback will safe if another request come in same callback function ?

Comment: i'm not 100% sure what you're asking. with nested callbacks, you are safe because each inner function is different (functions defined in other functions are built at outer function execution time), including closure, so as fas as the inner callback can tell, he's all that matters. if you recycle a global non-nested callback and tell it to do 3 things from 3 places, it depends on how the callback is written in regards to that being a problem or not, but typically, no, it's fine. if it works once, it will stay working.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to worry about thread safety and similar issues in your javascript code. All javascript is executed on the main thread. In fact, just about all operations in node happen on the same main thread (except a small number of tasks like DNS and file I/O which use the thread pool in libuv, but those all post back to the main thread via a queue which is read from when the main thread has reached the end of an event loop tick).

However, other issues such as race conditions *could* technically still occur in javascript, but from my experience that isn't too common.